# Trivialization of fibration by etale base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibre-bundles, fibration

Let $f:Y \to X$ be a smooth fibration over $\mathbb{C}$ in the sense that $X$ is a smooth, quasi-projective, connected variety and $f$ is a smooth, projective (surjective) morphism. Suppose that every fiber of $f$ is isomorphic. Does there exists a finite etale morphism
$g:Z \to X$ such that the base change of $f$ by $g$, $$h: Y \times_X Z \to Z,$$ is a locally trivial fiber bundle in the Zariski topology? Any hint/reference will be most welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by a locally trivial fiber bundle in the Zariski topology? Not sure if this is helpful but any smooth morphism etale locally on the base admits a section.

Comment: @DavidBenjaminLim It means you can find a covering of Z by Zariski open subsets such that over any open subset U, $h^{-1}(U)$ is $U$-isomorphic to $U \times F$, where $F$ is the fiber of $f$.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  The relative Isom scheme over $X$ between $Y$ and a product $X$-scheme, say $X\times Y_0$, is a torsor over $X$ for the automorphism group scheme of $Y_0$.  Since the characteristic is zero, this torsor is smooth over $X$.  Thus, there exists a locally closed subscheme of the torsor that is etale over $X$.  After base change by this locally closed subscheme, the pullback is isomorphic to a product scheme.  This question has been asked and answered before on MO . . .

Comment: @Jason: The OP asks foe a *finite* étale morphism, which of course does not always exist.

Comment: No. Let $X$ be a simply connected projective manifold with nontrivial Brauer group
 (for instance a K3 surface). Then there exists fibrations $Y\rightarrow X$ with all fibers isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^n$ which are not Zariski locally trivial. Since $X$ is simply connected, taking finite étale covering does not improve the situation.

Comment: To expand on abx's comment, let $X$ be a K3 surface over $\mathbf{C}$, and choose an $n$-torsion element in $H^2(X,\mathbf{G}_m)$. Then such an element comes from an azumaya algebra $\mathscr{A} \in H^1(X, \text{PGL}_n)$, corresponding to some Brauer-Severi scheme $Y \to X$. Now by construction $Y \to X$ is smooth proper whose (geometric) fibers are isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}^n$. I think this should do it, because if $\mathscr{A}$ is non-trivial to start with then $Y$ should not be Zariski locally trivial.

Comment: @abx It seems from your comment and that of Jason Starr that if I remove the condition of "finite" the question could have a positive answer. Is this true? If so, can someone suggest a reference (it seems from Jason's comment that this was answered elsewhere in MO, so a link to that would also be fine).

Comment: @abx  I missed that the OP wants the morphism to be finite.  The argument in my comment produces a quasi-finite etale morphism.